# RTI DDS spamming my display

Tags: c++, c, qnx, data-distribution-service

I am working on an embedded system running on QNX 6.4.1 that has several software servers communicating with each other.  Some of the folks on my project checked a whole bunch of DDS stuff straight into the main baseline and went on holiday. Of course it doesn't work right, **and** our configuration management tool (Perforce) is acting up too....

I finally got the mess to compile, but it's spewing messages at me from several of the servers, multiple times per second. Note that there are no `cout` nor `printf` calls printing this out to the display. I believe it's coming from the RTI DDS libraries themselves.

The message I see is `RTISystemClock_getTime:now {HEXNUMBER, HEXNUMBER} < 0`

A Google search does not enlighten much. Can somebody tell my why it keeps spamming me?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay Googlers!

It turns out that somehow my system clock had gotten set to 2045. Apparently that's after DDS time wraps (it is after 2038...), so it thought the time was less than zero...

In hindsight, that should have been obvious, but this new DDS code is unfamiliar and the interweb wasn't much help and the printout with hex time was terse and... insert excuse here.

Fixing the clock fixed it.